# I'm working with Reactjs and Tailwind CSS and having an issue with my pictures

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to be able to put my pictures in the code like:

```
 <img alt="profile" src="assets/profile-image.png"/>
```

But it's not working

I am however able to import my picture like:

```
<img src={pic} alt="profile"/>
```

Any thoughts to why the other way isn't working?
It just shows a broken link

Thanks

Comment: what build tool are you using ? `create-react-app`, `vite.js`, `custom webpack` ?

Comment: create-react-app

Comment: given the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/), it should work with simple import `import pic from './pic.png';`

Comment: if you want to declare your image like this `<img alt="profile" src="assets/profile-image.png"/>`, you should put your image the the `public` folder (i.e. `public/assets/image.png`). Here is the [folder structure](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/) of a create react app

Comment: before using `pic` make sure it is valid file